# run java file in windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I want to run a java project in windows. I first compiled the .class file in linux. Copy back to windows. Now under the path `H:\deletefiles` has `delete.class, delete.java, a.jar, b.jar`. The package for class delete is `deleteFiles`.

My java class path is `C:\program Files\Java\jre7\bin`, Where I have no access to write.

I run in command prompt `C:\program Files\Java\jre7\bin>`

```
java -cp H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles.delete
```

always has the problem could not find or load main class, what's the problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the actual class to be run. The `-cp H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles.delete` only defines the classpath to be used, but not *which* class you want to run (and you limit the classpath to a single class as well).

What you want is:

```
java -cp H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles delete
```

Note the blank (space) between `H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles` which means you are passing two parameters to the java command:

1. `-cp H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles` - the classpath to use
2. `delete` - the class to run

---

If you need the classes that are part of the jar files, you need to add them to the classpath as well:

```
java -cp H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles;H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles\a.jar;H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles\b.jar delete
```

Comment: If they contain classes that your class needs, then yes.

Comment: sorry to disturb again... if I add the package name java -cp H:\deleteFiles\deleteFiles deleteFiles.delete, it will still no class find. If dismiss the package, it will complain Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  (wrong nam
e: deleteFiles/delete) .....

Comment: If `delete.java` specifies `package deleteFiles`, then you need to specify the directory containing the package as the classpath: `-cp H:\deleteFiles`. This is all described in the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you should call delete.class in your java command line, like this:

> java -cp H:\deleteFiles\delete

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Yes, we do not need. but what's the problem?I always  do this in linux, no problem

Comment: that's correct, i edit my question and remove .class extension,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the classpath to the location which contains the package hierarchy. If your package is named `deleteFiles` the location needs to contain a directory named `deleteFiles` which contains the class file.

In your example you would run it with
`java -cp H:\ deleteFiles.delete`

Answer (score 0):

To execute a Java program you have two options. Using a class file or using a jar file.
If your program only contains a single source file, executing the class file would be fine. But if you have multiple sources, you would have to copy all of them. Then a jar would be more practicable.

For class:

```
java -cp <class path> <class name>
```

For jar (if the main class is set):

```
java -jar <jar file>
```